# Appending attributes to a variable on selection of multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

I have a dynamic grid which looks something like this

```
 Serial No(checkbox1)                  Document Name       Attachment
  1(checkbox2)                           abc               (img)
  2(checkbox2)                           xyz               (img)
  3(checkbox2)                           uio               (img)
  4(checkbox2)                           pop               (img)
```

Let me explain how this works. When the user clicks on the attachment img, it opens a dialog box which shows all the files attached in it. Each file will also have a checkbox against it. Lets call them checkbox3. If user selects the checkbox2 against serial number 1 then the checkboxes in the dialog box(dialog box of serail number 1 only) will also get checked.  In the same way if user selects checkbox2 of serail number 2 then the checkboxes of the relevant dialog box will also get checked.

Now if the user checks checkbox1 which is against the serailNo heading, then all checboxes from serial number 1 to 4 will get checked and so all the dialog boxes will also get checked.

Below is my code. If you run the snippet, you will understand what I am trying to explain.

```js
//on change of checkbox inside table..
$(document).on("change", "#AttachmentGrid .attachment_selection", function() {

  var total = $(".attachment_selection").length
  var get_code = $("#AttachmentGrid").data("code").split("_")[1] 
  //if all checked..
  if ($(".attachment_selection:checked").length == total) {
    $("#uploadGrid tr[cdCode=" + get_code + "]").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", true) 
  } else {
    $("#uploadGrid tr[cdCode=" + get_code + "]").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", false) 
  }

})
```

```css
#attchment_div {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="display" width="100%" id="uploadGrid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="Greyheader">
        <input type='checkbox' id='selectAll'>
        <br/>S.No</th>
      <th class="Greyheader">Document Name</th>
      <th class="Greyheader">Browse</th>
      <th class="Greyheader">Attachment</th>
      <th class="Greyheader">Save</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr id="517" cdCode="41701" mandatory="N">
    <td class="GreyBorder">
      1&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type='checkbox' id=chk_517 class='activity_selection'>
    </td>
    <td class="GreyBorder">
      <span>Letter</span>
    </td>
    <td class="GreyBorder" style=" text-align:center !important;">
      <input 
        type="file" 
        multiple="multiple" 
        name="txt_filePath_517" 
        class="mediumTextField" 
        id="txt_filePath_517" 
        style="width: 78%;"
      >
    </td>
    <td class="GreyBorder" style=" text-align:center !important;" align="center">
      <span style="cursor:hand">
        <span class="attch_counter">2</span>
        <img 
          title="Attachment" 
          height="20px" 
          onclick="AttchmentBox('_41701','2',this);" 
          src="../../Images/attchments.png" 
        />
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="GreyBorder" align="center">
      <img 
        type="image" 
        title="Save" 
        src="../../Images/save.png" 
        id="Btn_517" 
        onclick="SaveAttachment('517','41701','50818','50595');" 
        style="cursor:pointer;height:15px;" 
        class="AddItem" 
      />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="518" cdCode="41702" mandatory="N">
    <td class="GreyBorder">
      2&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type='checkbox' id=chk_518 class='activity_selection'>
    </td>
    <td class="GreyBorder">
      <span>Customer</span>
    </td>
    <td class="GreyBorder" style=" text-align:center !important;">
      <input 
        type="file" 
        multiple="multiple" 
        name="txt_filePath_518" 
        class="mediumTextField" 
        id="txt_filePath_518" 
        style="width: 78%;"
      >
    </td>
    <td class="GreyBorder" style=" text-align:center !important;" align="center">
      <span style="cursor:hand">
        <span class="attch_counter">1</span>
        <img 
          title="Attachment" 
          height="20px" 
          onclick="AttchmentBox('_41702','1',this);" 
          src="../../Images/attchments.png" 
        />
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="GreyBorder" align="center">
      <img 
        type="image"
        title="Save" 
        src="../../Images/save.png" 
        id="Btn_518" 
        onclick="SaveAttachment('518','41702','50818','50595');" 
        style="cursor:pointer;height:15px;" 
        class="AddItem" 
      />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="attchment_div">
  <table style="width:100%" id="AttachmentGrid">
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left; width:40%;">
        <input type='checkbox' id=chkAttachment_78427 class='attachment_selection' onclick="addAttributes('78427','41701',this);">
        <a 
          title="ABC.docx" 
          onclick="showDocument('78427');" 
          style='text-decoration: none;cursor: pointer;'
        >
          <div class='ui-notify-message ui-notify-message-style'>
            <div style='float:left;margin:0 10px 0 0' class='image_path'>
              <img src='../../Images/attchments.png'>
            </div>
            <p>ABC.docx</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:center; width:35%;">
        <div style='float:left;position:relative;top:-6px;'>
          <div class='date'>
            <span class='day'>10</span>
            <span class='month'>Jun</span>
            <span class='year'>2021</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width:20%; cursor:hand;">
        <img 
          viewtype="delete" 
          title="Delete Attachment" 
          style="float:right;padding-bottom:20px;" 
          src="../../images/delete.png" 
          onclick="DeleteAttachment('78427','41701')" 
          class="AddItem" 
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left; width:40%;">
        <input 
          type='checkbox' 
          id=chkAttachment_78424 
          class='attachment_selection' 
         onclick="addAttributes('78424','41701',this);"
        >
        <a 
          title="FOSUNDERSTANDING.docx" 
          onclick="showDocument('78424');" 
          style='text-decoration: none;cursor: pointer;'
        >
          <div class='ui-notify-message ui-notify-message-style'>
            <div style='float:left;margin:0 10px 0 0' class='image_path'>
              <img src='../../Images/attchments.png' />
            </div>
            <p>FOSUNDERSTANDING.docx</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:center; width:35%;">
        <div style='float:left;position:relative;top:-6px;'>
          <div class='date'>
            <span class='day'>09</span>
            <span class='month'>Jun</span>
            <span class='year'>2021</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width:20%; cursor:hand;">
        <img 
          viewtype="delete" 
          title="Delete Attachment" 
          style="float:right;padding-bottom:20px;" 
          src="../../images/delete.png" 
          onclick="DeleteAttachment('78424','41701')" 
          class="AddItem" 
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

```js
var docCodes = '';
    function addAttributes(docID, CdCode, el) {
        var str = docID + '♦';
        if ($(el).is(':checked')) {
            docCodes += str;
            alert(docCodes);
            console.log(docCodes);
        }
        else {
            docCodes = docCodes.replace(str, '');
            console.log(docCodes);
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is that on the selection of checkboxes I want the documnetcode of the files attached in the dialog box to append to a variable.

What I did was made an onclick function for the checkboxes inside the dialog box

```
   var docCodes = '';
    function addAttributes(docID, CdCode, el) {
        var str = docID + '♦';
        if ($(el).is(':checked')) {
            docCodes += str;
            alert(docCodes);
            console.log(docCodes);
        }
        else {
            docCodes = docCodes.replace(str, '');
            console.log(docCodes);
        }
    }
```

This is working fine but not in all scenarios. As there can be multiple scenarios

Scenario 1: The user opens this grid, right now it does not tick any checkboxes, he opens the dialog box against Sno 1, and checks the checkboxes against files attached.(Suppose there are 3 files attached) . Then my function will append the document code to my string docCodes.

Scenario 2 : The user opens a grid, and checks the Sno1 checkbox which means the checboxes in the dialog box will get auto ticked as well. In this case it should check if checkboxes in dialog box are ticked then append the relevant document code and if the user later unticks, remove that attribute.

Scenario 3 : The user directly checks the checkbox1 against serial number heading which will check all child checkboxes.

Right now only scenario 1 is working. How do I fulfill other two scenarios? PLease help.

Comment: how `addAttributes` function gets called ?

Comment: @Swati Hi its gets called on clicking of the checkbox inside the dialog box. But I think its not the right way. Since user can directly select the serial number checkbox. I am clueless how to do this way.

Comment: can you update html with that onclick and js code as well ?

Comment: @Swati I have updated my html. I actually dont know how this snippet thing works. I tried my best

Comment: @Swati the reason I want to append the document codes to a varaiable is because after the user selects the checkboxes he wants, he will press the download files button which will donwload the selected files only. So i want to gather all those codes in a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding them in some variable save them inside array . So , in below code i have added function call `addAttributes` whenever your sno is checked . Then , as we are not having `docCodes` there you can loop through checked checkboxes inside dialog and then push them inside array .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//on change of checkbox inside table..
$(document).on("change", "#AttachmentGrid .attachment_selection", function() {

  var total = $(".attachment_selection").length
  var get_code = $("#AttachmentGrid").data("code").split("_")[1]
  //if all checked..
  if ($(".attachment_selection:checked").length == total) {
    $("#uploadGrid tr[cdCode=" + get_code + "]").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", true)
  } else {
    $("#uploadGrid tr[cdCode=" + get_code + "]").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", false)
  }

})

function AttchmentBox(id, count, el) {

  if (parseInt(count) > 0) {

    $("#attchment_div #AttachmentGrid").find(".attachment_selection").prop("checked", false)

    if ($(el).closest("tr").find(".activity_selection").is(":checked")) {
      $("#attchment_div #AttachmentGrid").find(".attachment_selection").prop("checked", true)
      //sno is checked call your function: 
      addAttributes()

    }
    $("#attchment_div #AttachmentGrid").data("code", id) 
    $("#attchment_div").show() 
  }

}
var docCodes = [];

function addAttributes(docID, CdCode, el) {
  //el == undefined call from AttchmentBox
  if (el == undefined) {
    //loop through checked checkbox...
    $(".attachment_selection:checked").each(function() {
      var str = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];//id=chkAttachment_78424 .etc
      //if not inside array
      if (docCodes.indexOf(str) == -1) {
        docCodes.push(str) //push that in array
      }
    })

  } else {
    var str = docID;
    //if checked..and not inside array
    if ($(el).is(':checked') && docCodes.indexOf(str) == -1) {
      docCodes.push(str)
    } else {
      docCodes.splice(docCodes.indexOf(str), 1) //remove it..
    }
  }
  console.log(docCodes)
}
```

```css
#attchment_div {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="display" width="100%" id="uploadGrid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="Greyheader">
        <input type='checkbox' id='selectAll'>
        <br/>S.No</th>
      <th class="Greyheader">Document Name</th>
      <th class="Greyheader">Browse</th>
      <th class="Greyheader">Attachment</th>
      <th class="Greyheader">Save</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr id="517" cdCode="41701" mandatory="N">
    <td class="GreyBorder">
      1&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type='checkbox' id=chk_517 class='activity_selection'>
    </td>
    <td class="GreyBorder">
      <span>Letter</span>
    </td>
    <td class="GreyBorder" style=" text-align:center !important;">
      <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="txt_filePath_517" class="mediumTextField" id="txt_filePath_517" style="width: 78%;">
    </td>
    <td class="GreyBorder" style=" text-align:center !important;" align="center">
      <span style="cursor:hand">
        <span class="attch_counter">2</span>
      <img title="Attachment" height="20px" onclick="AttchmentBox('_41701','2',this);" src="../../Images/attchments.png" />
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="GreyBorder" align="center">
      <img type="image" title="Save" src="../../Images/save.png" id="Btn_517" onclick="SaveAttachment('517','41701','50818','50595');" style="cursor:pointer;height:15px;" class="AddItem" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="attchment_div">
  <table style="width:100%" id="AttachmentGrid">
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left; width:40%;">
        <input type='checkbox' id=chkAttachment_78427 class='attachment_selection' onclick="addAttributes('78427','41701',this);">
        <a title="ABC.docx" onclick="showDocument('78427');" style='text-decoration: none;cursor: pointer;'>
          <div class='ui-notify-message ui-notify-message-style'>
            <div style='float:left;margin:0 10px 0 0' class='image_path'>
              <img src='../../Images/attchments.png'>
            </div>
            <p>ABC.docx</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:center; width:35%;">
        <div style='float:left;position:relative;top:-6px;'>
          <div class='date'>
            <span class='day'>10</span>
            <span class='month'>Jun</span>
            <span class='year'>2021</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width:20%; cursor:hand;">
        <img viewtype="delete" title="Delete Attachment" style="float:right;padding-bottom:20px;" src="../../images/delete.png" onclick="DeleteAttachment('78427','41701')" class="AddItem" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left; width:40%;">
        <input type='checkbox' id=chkAttachment_78424 class='attachment_selection' onclick="addAttributes('78424','41701',this);">
        <a title="FOSUNDERSTANDING.docx" onclick="showDocument('78424');" style='text-decoration: none;cursor: pointer;'>
          <div class='ui-notify-message ui-notify-message-style'>
            <div style='float:left;margin:0 10px 0 0' class='image_path'>
              <img src='../../Images/attchments.png' />
            </div>
            <p>FOSUNDERSTANDING.docx</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:center; width:35%;">
        <div style='float:left;position:relative;top:-6px;'>
          <div class='date'>
            <span class='day'>09</span>
            <span class='month'>Jun</span>
            <span class='year'>2021</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width:20%; cursor:hand;">
        <img viewtype="delete" title="Delete Attachment" style="float:right;padding-bottom:20px;" src="../../images/delete.png" onclick="DeleteAttachment('78424','41701')" class="AddItem" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: So I have to call this function addAttributes inside my AttachmentGrid function only ? @Swati

Comment: Yes, see if that works at your end or if you need something else .

Comment: Let me try @swati

Comment: Hi but this only works when you click on the attachment image. what if the user just selects the serial number 1 checkbox , the checkboxes in the dialog box will get auto ticked and if the user does not click on the attachment image, is it going to work this way? Also what if the user unticks any checkbox from the dialog box , is that document going to be removed from the array? I mentioned all scenarios in my question @Swati

Comment: *if the user unticks any checkbox from the dialog box , is that document going to be removed from the array..* - yes (try in above code snippet) . Also , about `click on the attachment image. what if the user just se..` this can done as well ..but, question is from where we will get  docCodes because they are generated dynamically and only get generated on click of attachmnts  ?

Comment: 1)When I am unchecking from dialog box, my console is not showing the updated array. 2)Is there any way we can get docCodes  before?

Comment: 1- That is working fine above code (check if you ddCodes are fetching correctly or not ) . Also , did you see its working in above code snippet ? 2 - Save them in frontend like in some data-attribute .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233690/discussion-between-swati-and-unknown).